# Is there a better way to get the number of elements in a row?

Tags: c#

Right now I'm using something like the code below, does anyone know a better way of doing this?

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Dummy.Rows)
    {
        int length = row.ItemArray.Length;
    }
```

Comment: There is the DataTable.Columns collection that has the Count property. Just curious, what is table and Dummy in the code above?

Comment: It's an emulated table, basically mimicing a table with actual data in order to have a blank slate for user input. Depending on the table we're viewing, dummy is different, and so the number of col's varies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the DataTable.Columns collection that has the Count property. Thanks Steve for the answer

```
table.Dummy.Columns.Count
```